# Using Associated/Multi-Dimensional Array Data as Message Value in PHP Mail

Tags: php, email, multidimensional-array

I am trying to write a basic PHP Mail Function and it doesn't work when I try using Associated/Multi-Dimensional Array stored data "$emailer['pk']['cr']" for the Message value. No error message is sent/logged and the email fails to send. Switching the Message to a standard variable allows the email to process successfully.

How can i use the Associated Array data with the Mail function, is this not allowed or am i missing something?

```
/* I've Removed Header Data for Safety */

// Fails
$emailer['pk']['cr'] = "=====";
$emailer['pk']['cr'] .= "The message";
$emailer['pk']['cr'] .= "=====";

mail($to, $subject, $emailer['pk']['cr'], $headers);

// Works
$message = "An example message";    

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: And have you tried `$message = "=====The message=====";`?

Comment: Hi @PatrickQ yes that works fine

Comment: And what about `$message = $emailer['pk']['cr'];`? (and then using `$message` in the `mail()` call)

Comment: That has the same problem @PatrickQ, it should be working shouldn't it?

Comment: Make sure you have your error reporting turned on ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)).  I'm going to guess that there's something going on in code that you're not showing us.

Comment: Can I ask why you want to use multidimensional array to send simple text?  Are you joining variables from something else?  Show me everything and I can help.  Also @James Parry makes a good point.  Do what he said.

Comment: Error reporting is on and if it should work as intended i'll have to review the source code. Thank you @technology101010 for your offer, but there's lots of includes etc and wasn't written by myself. I'll have a go at making some test scripts and see if those shed any light. The main reason for the MD Array is for sorting and storing easily (lots of data going on and was easier to pass to sessions / database etc). The emails themselves are simple notification emails to various parties.